# Create unique random group id in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to create a unique, randomly assigned (without replacement) group id without using a for loop. This is as far as I got:

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

iris <- iris  %>% group_by(Species) %>% mutate(id = cur_group_id())
```

This gives me a group id for each iris$Species, however, I would like the group id to randomly assigned from c(1,2,3) as opposed to assigned based on the order of the dataset.

Any help creating this would be very helpful! I am sure there is a way to do this with dplyr but I am stumped...

Comment: Must they be 50,each? Or could you have different group sizes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can play some tricks on `group_by` by adding `sample` operation, e.g.,

```
iris <- iris %>%
  group_by(factor(Species, levels = sample(levels(Species)))) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id())
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample answer creating a random number and ranking them.

```r
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

data(iris)

df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(id = runif(1,0,1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(id = dense_rank(id))

df %>% sample_n(10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species       id
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>      <int>
#>  1          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa         3
#>  2          6.5         3            5.5         1.8 virginica      2
#>  3          6.3         2.7          4.9         1.8 virginica      2
#>  4          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa         3
#>  5          6.3         2.3          4.4         1.3 versicolor     1
#>  6          7.9         3.8          6.4         2   virginica      2
#>  7          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa         3
#>  8          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4 setosa         3
#>  9          6.4         2.8          5.6         2.2 virginica      2
#> 10          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2 setosa         3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That is a great trick.  I had never seen dense_rank before.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `sample` and `recode`:

1. Use `seq_along(unique(id))` to create a vector of integer values to recode to.
2. Use `sample` to sample the appropriate number of random values.
3. Use `setNames` to name the `id`s with their new random values.
4. Use `!!!` to force that vector of named `id` into a list of expressions.
5. use `recode` to change the values.

```
iris  %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id()) %>%
  mutate(id = recode(id, !!!setNames(unique(id),
                                     sample(seq_along(unique(id))))))
```

I think the other answers are better approachs, but having `recode` with `!!!` in your toolkit is helpful in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Randomise the rows and then assign `id` based on the occurrence of `Species` :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  slice_sample(n = nrow(.)) %>%
  #sample_n for dplyr < 1.0.0
  #sample_n(n()) %>%
  mutate(id = match(Species, unique(Species)))
```